# Eloqua - Cloud Connector and AppCloud

Tags: php, eloqua

I need to implement a `SMS sending service in Eloqua`.
To achieve this, I create a `AppCloud` and I added to it an `Action Service`.

I dont understand when the action of my app is triggered in a campaign. I know that there is a notification system. Is this system allows me to engage my action API ?

In my campaign I add a member segment in which I put myself and then I connect it to my cloud app action. On the side of my application I add a log system to check whether notification snaps , but it is never called.

Thank you very much for your attention

Answer (score 2):

In Eloqua, when creating an action service check the following configuration value:

> Send notification when members arrive in step

When members hit the step Eloqua will do a POST request to the action notify URL.
If you want the contact to be sent in the body of the request set:

> Records per Notification = 5000

In order to receive the contacts, the action create url will need to respond with a valid record definition:

```
{
   "recordDefinition" :
   {
      "ContactID" : "{{Contact.Id}}",
      "EmailAddress" : "{{Contact.Field(C_EmailAddress)}}"
   }
}
```

Here is the official documentation for the action service: http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAB/index.html#Developers/AppCloud/Develop/develop-action-service.htm